# comparing strings - Lua

Tags: string, lua

I have a file (termino.txt) that is all filled in the following format :

1. pay the bill
2. 2015-08-30T13:22:53.108Z
3. Go to the doctor
4. 2015-09-30T13:22:53.108Z
5. ....

All the even lines are of the form RFC 3339 timestamp. What I need is to compare today's date with these dates the file to see if they are the same. I'm trying this:

```
  local function verifica(evt)
    local nome= ''
    local dia = ''
    local turn = 1
    local data = os.date("%x")
    local file = io.open("termino.txt", "r")
    while true do
         nome = dia
         line = file:read()
         dia = line

         if (turn %2 == 0) then

          > Here I need to compare "data" with "dia" that will receive string with RFC 3339 timestamp format.


         end
    turn ++ 
    end

end
```

I need help to make this comparison! Thanks

Comment: `local data = os.date("%F")`, compare first 10 chars `if data == line:sub(1,10) then`

Comment: I'm in brazil. So I guess when I run local data = os.date("%F"), the format will be "DD/MM/YYYY" but in file the format is "YYYY-MM-DD" ! how do I fix it?

Comment: Use `os.date"%Y-%m-%d"`

Answer (score 0):

```
local dia = '2015-10-6T13:22:53.108Z'
-- parse date info from the RFC 3339 timestamp
local year, month, day = dia:match('(%d+)-(%d+)-(%d+)')
-- get today's date from Lua, in table format
local today = os.date('*t')
-- compare
if    tonumber(year)  == today.year
  and tonumber(month) == today.month
  and tonumber(day)   == today.day then
    -- the dates match
end
```

Comment: You'd also need `tonumber`/`tostring` calls.

Comment: @Mud - In Lua string "123" is not equal to number 123.

Comment: Doh. How I've been programming in Lua this long and not known that, I dunno. Cheers.